# Why is State and Country a text input in Visualforce when I have State/Country picklists enabled?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, address

Are State and Country Picklist supported in Visualforce?

I'm trying to access them on Visualforce for Contact object but only a Textbox is displayed instead of a Dropdown.

My code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've enabled Country and State Picklist in my org, and it shows perfectly fine in Standard Contact Edit form:
[image]

Comment: Thnx for the Editing @Ralph. Next time I'll keep in mind these corrections.

Comment: Happy to help @varun.  Picture was very helpful, an excellent inclusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sry Found the solution to the question just after entering the Question.

The correct Field that should be referenced in Visualforce page is "MailingCountryCode" instead of "MailingCountry"

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCountryCode}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This code should work fine.

Comment: Same thing for `MailingStateCode` instead of `MailingState`